# How to let users download multiple files in Spring MVC using model object?

Tags: spring, mongodb, file, model-view-controller, download

When users click a link, I need to show them Description, images as well as send multiple files for them to download.
I used Spring data to get an object with few String variables, List of images as well as documents from mongodb and added this object to Model. I am able to display Description and images after converting Binary data to String and using th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+image}" on the html page. Till this part, it's fine. But I am not sure how to let users download pdf files which are in Binary format in the Model. Please help. Please see screenshots. When I open this page, along with Description & images, I should get a prompt that there are files for download. How can I acheive this [image]

```
public class EventPostsDTO {
    private String postId;
    private Long eventId;
    private String description;
    private List<MultipartFile> images;
    private List<MultipartFile> receipts;
    private List<String> imgAsStrings;
    private Map<String,Binary> receiptsMap;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private Event event;
    //getters and setters
}
```

HTML Page with Thymeleaf

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
                xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
            <head>
            <title>Event Feed</title>
            <link th:include="fragments/header::includecss">
            </head>
            <body>
                <section th:replace="fragments/header::header"></section>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <section class="header4 cid-r8pwxTO9dF mbr-parallax-background"
                    id="header4-14">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2 th:text="${event.eventName}"
                            class="mbr-section-title align-center pb-3  mbr-fonts-style display-1">
                            INTRO WITH IMAGE</h2>
                        <div th:each="post : ${posts}">
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                                <div class="media-content col-md-10">
                                    <div class="mbr-text align-left pb-3">
                                        <h3 class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-5"
                                            th:text="${post.description}"></h3>
                                        <em class="mbr-fonts-style"
                                            th:text="${'Posted on '+post.creationDate}">Intro with
                                            background image, color overlay and a picture at the bottom.
                                            Mobirise helps you cut down development time by providing you
                                            with a flexible website editor with a drag and drop interface.</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div th:each="image : ${post.imgAsStrings}">
                                    <div class="mbr-figure pt-5">
                                        <img th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+image}" alt=""
                                            width="100%" height="auto" class="imgdiv" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div th:each="receipt : ${post.receiptsMap}">
                                    <embed src="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf" th:src="${receipt.key}" width="600"
                                        height="500" alt="pdf"
                                        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
                                    </embed>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </section>
                <section th:replace="fragments/footer::footer"></section>
                <script
                    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            </body>
```

Comment: Using the model object is not the right solution. You don't want to display something inside an HTML page Your want the bytes of the PDF file to constitute the response body. Googling for "Spring MVC download file" gives plenty of results. Read them.

Comment: Thank you. So, I should show a list of files in this page as links instead, and when user clicks on the file he wants to download, I should send the file in response body?

Comment: Yes, most probably. You can also use black magic like a hidden iframe to immediately start a download, but you can only download one file at a time. If you want to download them all at once, then you'll need to download a zip containing all the files. My point is that the download whether it's triggered by a click on a link or by a hidden iframe loading a URL, will be done in a separate request, and the response of that request must be the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Boot, Spring Data Mongo then you should consider using [Spring Content Mongo](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for the content storage pieces like this:

Add the following dependencies to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-mongo-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you have a GridFsTemplate bean present in your application context.  Something like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig

   @Bean
   public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
      return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
   }
   ...
```

To allow content to be associated with your Entity, give it the following attributes:

```
public class Event {

    ... other attributes ...

    List<Image> images;
    List<Recepit> receipts;
}

public class Image {
    @ContentId
    private String contentId;

    @ContentLength 
    private long contentLength = 0L;

    @MimeType
    private String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
}

public class Receipt {
    @ContentId
    private String contentId;

    @ContentLength 
    private long contentLength = 0L;

    @MimeType
    private String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
}
```

Add a store interface:

```
@StoreRestResource
public interface EventImage extends ContentStore<Image, String> {
}

@StoreRestResource
public interface EventReceipt extends ContentStore<Receipt, String> {
}
```

That's all that you need.  When you application starts Spring Content will see the dependencies on the Mongo/REST modules and it will inject an implementation of the `ImageStore` and `ReceiptStore` for GridFs as well as an implementation of a controller that supports full CRUD functionality and maps those operations down onto the underlying store interfaces.  You will have REST endpoints available under `/events/{eventId}/images` and `/events/{eventId}/receipts`.

So

`curl -X PUT /events/{eventId}/images -F 'file=@path/to/local/image'` will upload a new image and append it to the list `List<Image>`

`curl -X GET /events/{eventId}/images/` will get you a list of images

`curl -X GET /events/{eventId}/images/{contentId}` will fetch an event image

`curl -X DELETE /events/{eventId}/images/{contentId}` will delete the event image

Receipts would work the same way.

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content for the filesystem but the modules are interchangeable.  The Mongo reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/mongo-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).

HTH